# Chrome Extension Top Visited List

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make an extension that looks at your most visited sites and then tells you things about yourself given those sites.

I'm a bit lost with how to go about this and was wondering, do I run the script with the background.js file? or when they click the popup?

This is the code I'm looking to replicate,

```
// Event listener for clicks on links in a browser action popup.
// Open the link in a new tab of the current window.
function onAnchorClick(event) {
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: event.srcElement.href });
  return false;
}

// Given an array of URLs, build a DOM list of these URLs in the
// browser action popup.
function buildPopupDom(mostVisitedURLs) {
  var popupDiv = document.getElementById('mostVisited_div');
  var ol = popupDiv.appendChild(document.createElement('ol'));

  for (var i = 0; i < mostVisitedURLs.length; i++) {
    var li = ol.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
    var a = li.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
    a.href = mostVisitedURLs[i].url;
    a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(mostVisitedURLs[i].title));
    a.addEventListener('click', onAnchorClick);
  }
}

chrome.topSites.get(buildPopupDom);
```

This is sort of not working at the moment.

Comment: Make sure you use the correct devtools: the popup is a separate window so it has its own one, accessible by right-clicking inside the popup. Make sure to declare "topSites" in manifest.json. Make sure to declare the "browser_action" popup and its script inside properly as shown in the documentation and demo extensions. P.S. you can simply use `a.target = '_blank'` instead of a listener.

Comment: Can you expand on "not working"? What happens when you run this code?